# How to use Hugepage memory in kernel mode?

Tags: c, linux

How to use Hugepage memory in kernel mode? how
user mode ：

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *m;
  size_t s = (8UL * 1024 * 1024);
 
  m = mmap(NULL, s, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                    MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | 0x40000 /*MAP_HUGETLB*/, -1, 0);
  if (m == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("map mem");
    m = NULL;
    return 1;
  }
 
  memset(m, 0, s);
 
  printf("map_hugetlb ok, press ENTER to quit!\n");
  getchar();
 
  munmap(m, s);
  return 0;
}
```

How to use Hugepage memory in kernel mode?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The kernel equivalent are Transparent Huge Pages which are a kernel feature you enable (and possibly already have enabled), so you just allocate what you need as you would anything. https://lwn.net/Articles/423584/  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70400853/how-to-open-and-use-huge-page-and-transparent-huge-page-in-code-on-ubuntu